# MYSQL database search using PHP to display result

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a search bar in a HTML form that allows the user to search their postcode e.g. m6 and get a corresponding postage price e.g. 0.50. My database has 2 fields: postcode & price.

When the user searches I am trying to get the PHP to echo the result of the price via a session away from the processing page. Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to this!

The problem is that the session does not appear to be saving the result.

index.php:

```
 <section id="post">
   <p id="post"> postage calculator for manchester: </P>

   <?php echo 'total cost £'. $_SESSION['postage']; ?>

    <form action="shop.php" method="post">
      <input class="text" type="text" name="postsub" min="0">
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="postsub1" value="postsub" >
    </form>
</section>
```

process.php:

```
else if(array_key_exists('postsub1', $_POST)) {
  button6();
}

function button6() {
  session_start();
  $search_value = $_POST["postsub"];

  $dbname='aee553_webdata';
  $codequery = "SELECT price FROM postage WHERE postcode LIKE '%$search_value%'";

  $dbh= new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname,$username,$password);

  $result= $dbh->query($codequery);
  $_SESSION['postage'] = $result ;
  header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Am I along the right lines or am I completely off? Any solution would be great.

Comment: What's your actual problem? What's not working and how?

Comment: Also, This code is extremely susceptible to [sql injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/). You should use [prepared statements with parameter binding](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Comment: The problem is that the session does not appear to be saving the result.

Comment: Do you also have `session_start();` at the top of the index.php file (or in a script which is included in that one)?

Comment: Does your `index.php` have a `session_start();` at the top of it too?

Comment: @ADyson yes I do, i have no idea why it is not displaying the result

Comment: Also, its a bit odd to have the `session_start();` inside your `button6()` function. Instead, Id expect `session_start();` to be at the top of the script that calls `button6()`.  While we're at it, `button6` isnt a very descriptive name for a function.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$result` when its set to `$_SESSION['postage'] = $result ;`? can you do a `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: [The docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) seem to indicate that $result is an object, not a string value you could use as you have "PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object"

Comment: Perhaps you need something like `$result= $dbh->query($codequery, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` then `$_SESSION['postage'] = isset($result['price']) ? $result['price']  : '';`

Comment: when i do var dump it displays this: object(PDOStatement)[2]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT price FROM postage WHERE postcode LIKE '%m6%'' (length=52)

Comment: pdo->query returns a PDO statement object (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php). It doesn't return the price field directly (it can't, because clearly it's very common in a query result to a) have multiple fields and b) have multiple rows). That may well not be helping. You need to loop through the rows and pick the value out of the array. There are examples of this task in the documentation.

Comment: P.S. You seem to have assumed that your query will only return one row. But since you're using a LIKE condition, there's a very good chance it won't.

Comment: @WesleySmith good point but I suspect your example needs tweaking - in the docs it shows iterating over the $result object to get each row, and then referring to field indexes within each row object. You can't refer to an index on $result directly.

Comment: @ADyson Indeed, I _think_ the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` second param would handle that being shorthand for `$pdo->query($query)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` , but for sure only if the query had a LIMIT 1 though.